# nav menu displaying .current_menu_item css for multiple items

Tags: css, wordpress, navigationbar

The site in question is www.valuetactics.com

I want the menu item link of the current page to be bold and yellow.  If the child page is the active one, the child link item and the parent link item should both be bold and yellow.

Currently on the homepage there are multiple menu items in yellow, when it should just be the "Home" link.  I've tried altering the colors with

```
.main-navigation .current-menu-item > a{
color: yellow;
font-weight: bold;
}

.main-navigation .current-menu-ancestor > a{
color: white;
font-weight: bold;
}

 .main-navigation .current_page_ancestor > a {
color: green;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

Which I expanded from the default:

```
    .main-navigation .current-menu-item > a, .main-navigation .current-menu-ancestor > a, .main-navigation .current_page_item > a, .main-navigation .current_page_ancestor > a {
    color: yellow;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

I found that .main-navigation .current-menu-item controls the link color for the current page, but I can't figure out why this also affects all other menu items that have any child menu items.

This is a child theme of "twentytwelve" on wordpress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not with your CSS. You have multiple top-level menu items pointing to the home page, so the WordPress app is applying `.current-menu-item` to those as well. This is expected and appropriate behavior.

Change those top-level menu items to static placeholders, or point them to one of the child item pages instead.

Comment: Thanks!  You're right.  My placeholder link urls were still in the parent level menu items from when I first created the menu.  Guess it just takes a second pair of eyes sometimes.